# how do I write a where clause in SOQL that contains a field from the child relationship?

Tags: soql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT Id, Name, (select name, Phone, Email FROM Contacts) FROM Account
```

the table `Account` has a child relationship with `Contacts`.

this is the result of the query:

[image: Image 1]

I want to add a where clause to this query, that will filter the contacts and show me only the record of a contact who's name is "Elon Musk".

This is the child record result:

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your nested query works the same way as basic queries. So you just have to add a `WHERE` clause inside:

```
SELECT Id, Name, 
    (SELECT Name, Phone, Email 
        FROM Contacts 
        WHERE 
        Name = 'Elon Musk') 
FROM Account
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! dumb me.. didn't even think about editing the nested query

Comment: @D.Griff - Please accept answer if it was the correct one so others looking for similar issues can find answered questions.....